Find all integer $x, y$ such that $x(x+1)(x+2)(3x+1)=24y^2$
Find all integer $x, y$ such that $$x(x+1)(x+2)(3x+1)=24y^2.$$
Wolfram Alpha shows that the only answers are $$(-2,0), (-1,0), (0,0), (1, \pm 1), (3, \pm 5).$$
I couldn’t quite prove it yet. My plan was as follows. One of $x,$ $x+1,$ $x+2$ is always divisible by $3$. If $x$ is even then $x(x+2)$ is divisible by $8$. If $x$ is odd then $(x+1)(3x+1)$ is divisible by $8$. So, in any case we can divide both sides by $24$.
One of $x$, $x+1$, $x+2$ gets divided by $3$. And then two of $x$, $x+1$, $x+2$, $3x+1$ get divided by powers of $2$. The RHS is now a perfect square.
Now, $x$ is always coprime to $x+1$ and to $3x+1$. It is also coprime to $x+2$, if $x$ is odd. Otherwise $2$ can be a common factor. This means that either $|x|$, or $\frac{|x|}2$, or $\frac{|x|}3$, or $\frac{|x|}6$ is an exact square.
Consider $x+1$. It is coprime to $x$ and to $x+2$. It is also coprime to $3x+1$, if $x$ is even. Otherwise $2$ can be a common factor. This means that either $|x+1|$, or $\frac{|x+1|}2$, or $\frac{|x+1|}3$, or $\frac{|x+1|}6$ is an exact square.
Overall, these are the cases to consider:
$$(1)\quad |x|=a^2,\quad |x+1|=b^2$$
$$(2)\quad |x|=2a^2,\quad |x+1|=b^2$$
$$(3)\quad |x|=3a^2,\quad |x+1|=b^2$$
$$(4)\quad |x|=6a^2,\quad |x+1|=b^2$$
$$(5)\quad |x|=a^2,\quad |x+1|=2b^2$$
$$(6)\quad |x|=3a^2,\quad |x+1|=2b^2$$
$$(7)\quad |x|=a^2,\quad |x+1|=3b^2$$
$$(8)\quad |x|=2a^2,\quad |x+1|=3b^2$$
$$(9)\quad |x|=a^2,\quad |x+1|=6b^2$$
The first case gives $x=0, -1$. Case $(5)$ is actually the same as $(2)$, $(7)$ as $(3)$, $(8)$ as $(6)$, $(9)$ as $(4)$. Cases $(2),(3),(4),(6)$ are Pell, negative Pell, or Pell-like equations. They have infinitely many solutions. How even to choose from them?
Could this be salvaged, or is there a more simple approach?
(About the context, this equation arose when I tried to find all such positive integer $x$ that $(1^3+2^3+\dots+x^3)+(1^2+2^2+\dots+x^2)$ is a perfect square.)

$(x+1)(x+2)(3x+1)(6x)=(12y)^2$ thus 6x(x+1)=(x+2)(3x+1)$ for example.

It may be helpful to note that $x+2$ will be coprime to $3x+1$ unless $x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$, in which case both will be divisible by $5$. In particular, if $x+2 = 5k$, then $3x+1 = 5(3k-1)$. So the only prime factors that might be shared among the elements of the multiplication are $2$ (either between $x$ and $x+2$, or between $x+1$ and $3x+1$) and $5$ (possibly shared between $x+2$ and $3x+1$).
This means that after removing a factor of $3$ from whichever number is divisible by $3$, a factor of $2$ from an even number not divisible by $4$, and possibly a factor of $5$ from $x+2$ and $3x+1$, each of the four numbers being multiplied must be a square, since the right-hand side will be $(2y)^2$, and the four numbers being multiplied will all be pairwise coprime.

$Y^2 = 18x^4+60x^3+54x^2+12x$ with $Y=12y.$
Using online Magma calculator as follows.
               IntegralQuarticPoints([18,60,54,12,0]);  

It says that all integral points are $(( 1, 12 ), ( 3, -60 ), ( 0, 0 ), ( -1, 0 ), ( -2, 0 ))$.
Hence, all integral points are $(x,y)=(1,\pm 1),(3,\pm 5),(0,0),(-1,0),(-2,0).$
See related info MO
